# Dynamically added controls are not visible in UWP C#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, stackpanel

I'm trying to create a download manager for UWP in C#. I need to add ProgressBar for download progress, TextBlock for showing download status and another TextBox for displaying download file name. My code works fine when I compile only download manager's code separately (on a new uwp app). It shows progress properly in runtime.
My codes are-

```
private async void Downloadbtn_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri url = new Uri(urlBox.Text);
        string fileName = ResolveName(urlBox.Text);
        FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*.*");
        StorageFolder downloadfolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

        if (folderPicker != null)
        {
            StorageFile downloadFile = await downloadfolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
            operation = downloader.CreateDownload(url, downloadFile);

            try
            {

                TextBlock fileNameText = new TextBlock();
                fileNameText.Text = fileName;
                ProgressBar ProgressIndicator = new ProgressBar();
                ProgressIndicator.Name = "progress";
                TextBlock progressText = new TextBlock();
                progressText.Name = "progressText";

                StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
                panel.Children.Add(fileNameText);
                panel.Children.Add(ProgressIndicator);
                panel.Children.Add(progressText);
                MainStack.Children.Add(panel);

                cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                Progress<DownloadOperation> progressCallBack = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(Progress);
                await operation.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.Token,progressCallBack);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                await operation.ResultFile.DeleteAsync();
                operation = null;
            }


        }
    }

    private string ResolveName(string fileName)
    {
        if (fileName.Contains("/"))
        {
            int last = fileName.LastIndexOf("/");
            fileName = fileName.Substring(last + 1, fileName.Length - last - 1);
        }
        if (fileName.Contains("%20"))
        {
            fileName = fileName.Replace("%20", " ");
        }

        return fileName;
    }

    private void Progress(DownloadOperation operation)
    {
        ProgressBar c = new ProgressBar();
        c = (ProgressBar)(MainStack.FindName("progress" ));
        TextBlock c1 = new TextBlock();
        c1 = (TextBlock)(MainStack.FindName("progressText"));

        double received = operation.Progress.BytesReceived;
        double toReceive = operation.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive;
        double progress = received * 100 / toReceive;
        ((ProgressBar)c).Value = progress;
        c1.Text = received + "KB received of " + toReceive + "KB";

        if (received == toReceive) 
            c1.Text = "Download Completed";
    }
```

MainStack is the stackpanel where new download and its ui elements are added.

But UI elements (progressbar, textblock) are not visible when I'm putting above codes in a different app like-

```
private async void GetDownloadData(Uri uri)
    {
        string fileName = ResolveName(uri.tostring());
        FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*.*");
        StorageFolder downloadfolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

        if (folderPicker != null)
        {
            StorageFile downloadFile = await downloadfolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
            operation = downloader.CreateDownload(url, downloadFile);

            try
            {

                TextBlock fileNameText = new TextBlock();
                fileNameText.Text = fileName;
                ProgressBar ProgressIndicator = new ProgressBar();
                ProgressIndicator.Name = "progress" ;
                TextBlock progressText = new TextBlock();
                progressText.Name = "progressText";

                StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
                panel.Children.Add(fileNameText);
                panel.Children.Add(ProgressIndicator);
                panel.Children.Add(progressText);
                MainStack.Children.Add(panel);

                cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                Progress<DownloadOperation> progressCallBack = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(Progress);
                await operation.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.Token,progressCallBack);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                await operation.ResultFile.DeleteAsync();
                operation = null;
            }


        }
    }
```

In the second code, I'm calling GetDownloadData(uri) method to initiate download rather than calling it upon button click event. And also this method is placed in different XAML page (other than main page).

The only problem with the second code is that, no progressbar or textblock is added at run time in MainStack (stackpanel). I tried solving this problem by replacing stackpanel with listview and listbox but problem doesn't resolve.
Any idea, what am I missing here.

Comment: Try this split out the control updates to a different method, call it first then call your async await.  That way, you are ensuring the code to add the elements is correct and that you're not bumping into dispatcher issues.

Comment: Thanks IInspectable, but I found the solution myself. I was calling the GetDownloadData(uri) method using an object, which will ensure the destruction of that object and all related data after the call has finished and it gets out of its scope. And that was the reason why UI elements of that call weren't visible. Actually, they were created and destroyed at once and so were not visible. I solved the problem by passing download uri through 'Frame.Navigate()' method, that kept UI elements intact even after completion of call.   Since I didn't get the solution from StackOverflow, I'm deleting it.